# Webhook trigger for Jenkins job from multiple BitBucket repositories

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks

I have a use case where I want to trigger a specific Jenkins job from a BitBucket pull-request via a webhook.

I have managed to get this working using the [Bitbucket Pull Request Builder Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-pullrequest-builder-plugin). However, this plugin only allows me to link one BitBucket repository to trigger my job, when I want to allow multiple repositories to trigger this job.

After doing some digging, I discovered that I could use the [Multiple SCMs Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin) to specify all of the repositories that I want to trigger the job. However, the [Multiple SCMs Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin) does not expose what `GIT_COMMIT` from which repository triggered the job.

Is there any way to either:

1. Use the [Bitbucket Pull Request Builder Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-pullrequest-builder-plugin) (or similar) to specify more than one repository to trigger from.
2. Get the [Multiple SCMs Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin) (or similar) to expose the `GIT_COMMIT` and repository that triggered the job?

I am currently limited to running an older version of Jenkins 
2.106, on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. I wanted to use web-hooks for my project, but it appeared that our infrastructure is so "secured" that web-hook's communication was blocked by security setup (Csrf issue). So I changed approach and create trigger job on `repoX` that can change.

**project-build-trigger** - freestyle job that points to `repoX`, with pool SCM (cron: 0/3 ****  - check each 3 minutes), and build when pushed to BitBucket

**project-deployment** - full pipeline job that points to `repoY` with option "`build after other projects are build`" (under `Build Triggers`) and set there  `project-build-trigger` (You cans set here other projects like: some library build job, some other jobs etc.)